# Current through cross coupled pairs

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis

I recently came across this question in a series of articles about cross coupled pairs by Razavi:

**In Figure 6, M1 and M2 are biased
and balanced by I1 and I2 ^ h I I 1 2 = .
At t = 0, Iin jumps from zero
to a small positive value, I0. We
intuitively expect that VX rises and
VY falls. However, viewing the XCP
as a resistance equal to -2/ , gm we
obtain V g XY = -( /2 m) ( I u0 t), concluding
that VX should descend
and VY should ascend! How do we
explain the discrepancy between
these two results?**

[image]

based on the figure in the image.

Now, intuitively I expected that Vx would fall and Vy would rise as a positive current is flowing into Vx, doesn't that imply Vy has a more positive potential? Or is this a sign convention thing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you assuming that the current source \$I{in}\$ must have a higher potential on its right side than on its left side, to produce current to the left? If so, that's where you've gone wrong. It's a current source, and can have *any potential difference*, positive, negative, zero, whatever.

Current sources simply produce whatever potential difference is necessary to produce their current. They are not like resistors, where current in them always flows from higher potential end to lower. Resistors always receive power, but current sources can both receive and produce power to the rest of the circuit, and consequently the only information we have regarding them is *current direction and magnitude*. In isolation we know nothing about the voltage across them.

Therefore, you can never determine the polarity of potential difference across a current source based solely on the direction of current through it, because it's also a function of everything else around the source.

Allow me to illustrate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8WkzT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In all cases, the current source is passing 1A to the left, and yet in each case the potential difference across it is different. The voltage can be positive, negative or even zero, depending on its periphery.

<sub>Note: Interestingly, in every case here, the battery on the left is charging, while the battery on the right is discharging.</sub>

In your example, the author suggests that the natural intuition is to assume \$V_X\$ increases due to \$I_{in}\$, which makes sense. Node X is the capacitive gate of FET M2, and with current flowing *into* that gate (as indicated by the direction of \$I_{in}\$), the potential at node X must be rising with respect to M2's source.

Similarly, since current direction is to the left, current is *leaving* the capacitive gate of M1 (node Y), and so node Y is falling in potential with respect to M1's source.

All the while, \$I_{in}\$ has *whatever* potential difference is needed to make it all happen this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of stability, this circuit exhibits negative resistance and is hence unstable.

Any static quiescent point is a possible equilibrium, so if you force \$I_\text{in}\$ current **and** \$V_\text{Y}=-V_\text{X}={I_\text{in}}/{g_\text{m}}\$ circuit will (only ideally) remain in this condition if non perturbed and exhibit the expected negative resitance.

But if you, from any such an unstable equilibrium point, try apply any disturbance, system output will diverge.

You could try a different experiment: replace current disturbance \$I_\text{in}\$ with a voltage one.

[image]

In this case intuition (VD1 up, VG2 up, ID2 up, some current is sunk into Vin) matches math analisys.

Now system has become stable, why? What is the boundary condition?

The key point is negative resistance:

When you drive by an ideal current source, as anticipated, total equivalent resistance seen at X,Y nodes is negative \$r_\text{o}=-2/g_\text{m}\$

On the other hand driving by ideal voltage source you actually shunt ro with 0Ω internal resistance depleting negative resistance.

[image]
In between we have driving by Norton equivalent of some non-ideal generator, whenever \$R_\text{N}<r_\text{o}\$ total parallel resistance \$R_\text{eq}\$ is positive and system stable.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. I do understand that this is an unstable system, that it exhibits negative resistance by virtue of it s regenerative feedback. If I am not wrong in understanding, does it imply that Y rising and X falling when Iin jumps from 0 to positive imply a stable equilibrium, contrary to negative resistance behavior?

Answer (score -2):

Suppose the current sources are 1mA; suppose the FETs have enough stripes to have transconductance of 0.001 (1mA/volt) at 1ma.

Apply the currents, impose a Vgs+Vt to have exactly 1mA through each transistor,
then release the gates of the 2 FETs.

What happens? The 2 FET channels have random electron noise, computable as (close enough) 4nanoVolts RMS * sqrt(bandwidth) where bandwidth is

$$ Freq bandwidth = transconductance / (2 * pi * gatecapacitance)  $$

Let gatecapacitance be 1pF (its a pretty big transistor, have gm of 0.001)
thus bandwidth is 160MHz. Sqrt(160MHz is 12,000) thus the voltage noise in each of the FET channels is 12,000 * 4nV rms = 48,000 NV or 48uV. RMS.

Comment: I understand your analysis but how would that lead to the expectation that Vx rises and Vy falls?

Comment: The two  random channel noise sources will fight, and one will randomly win; the larger may be more positive, or more negative, driving that FET output (which is inverting) more negative or more positive.